# Stream API and Queues: Subscribe to BlockingQueue stream-style

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Let's say we have a Queue

```
BlockingQueue<String> queue= new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
```

and some other thread puts values in it, then we read it like

```
while (true) {
    String next = queue.take();
    System.out.println("next message:" + next);
}
```

How can I iterate over this queue in stream style, while maintaining similar semantics to above code.

This code only traverses the current queue state:

```
queue.stream().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));
```

Comment: This should work. That is a correct syntax. What made you say so?

Comment: As an explanation of what the issue is: The code using the `while` loop does not terminate, and prints each String put into the queue. The stream example below only prints the elements that were inside the queue at the time of creating the stream - i.e. a finite number.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I'm guessing a bit at what you're expecting, but I think I have a good hunch.

The stream of a queue, like iterating over a queue, represents the **current contents** of the queue. When the iterator or the stream reaches the tail of the queue, it doesn't block awaiting further elements to be added. The iterator or the stream is exhausted at that point and the computation terminates.

If you want a stream that consists of all current and future elements of the queue, you can do something like this:

```
Stream.generate(() -> {
        try {
            return queue.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            return "Interrupted!";
        }
    })
    .filter(s -> s.endsWith("x"))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

(Unfortunately the need to handle `InterruptedException` makes this quite messy.)

Note that there is no way to close a queue, and there is no way for `Stream.generate` to stop generating elements, so this is effectively an infinite stream. The only way to terminate it is with a short-circuiting stream operation such as `findFirst`.

Comment: this is nice approach but my problem with it how to stop stream from working?

Comment: @BoboZohdy I'm not sure what you're asking. Maybe you should ask a separate question, and provide an example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: The Spliterator answer below answers this question far better.

Answer (score 19):

Another approach is to build a custom Spliterator. In my case, I've got a blocking queue, and I want to build a stream that continues to extract elements, until the block times out. The spliterator is something like:

```
public class QueueSpliterator<T> implements Spliterator<T> {
    private final BlockingQueue<T> queue;
    private final long timeoutMs;

    public QueueSpliterator(final BlockingQueue<T> queue, final long timeoutMs) {
        this.queue = queue;
        this.timeoutMs = timeoutMs;
    }

    @Override
    public int characteristics() {
        return Spliterator.CONCURRENT | Spliterator.NONNULL | Spliterator.ORDERED;
    }

    @Override
    public long estimateSize() {
        return Long.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(final Consumer<? super T> action) {
        try {
            final T next = this.queue.poll(this.timeoutMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            if (next == null) {
                return false;
            }
            action.accept(next);
            return true;
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            throw new SupplierErrorException("interrupted", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator<T> trySplit() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

The exception thrown to handle InterruptedException is an extension of RuntimeException. Using this class, one can build a stream via:
    StreamSupport.stream(new QueueSpliterator(...))
and add the usual stream operations.

Comment: this can be simplified with `Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong (but that's what I'm seeing). The problem with this is that you can't terminate the stream when you're done - it will keep polling for several timeout periods before completing.

Answer (score 15):

You could look at an async Queue implementation. If you have Java 8, then [cyclops-react](https://github.com/aol/cyclops-react), I a developer on this project, provides an async.Queue that will allow you to both populate and consume from the Queue asyncrhonously (and cleanly).

e.g.

```
Queue<String> queue = QueueFactories.<String>unboundedQueue().build();
```

Or simply (as long as this is a com.aol.simple.react.async.Queue)

```
Queue<String> queue = new Queue<>();
```

Then in a separate thread :

```
new Thread(() -> {
        while (true) {
            queue.add("New message " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
    }).start();
```

Back on your main thread, your original code should now work as expected  (infinetely iterate over the messages being added to the queue and print them out)

```
queue.stream().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));
```

The Queue and hence the Stream can be closed at any stage via -

```
queue.close();
```

Comment: I tried this example, it does not work as expected: the main thread isn't blocked on the forEach

Comment: Hi @Laymain - thanks for trying this out! What version are you using? I've tested the code above against the latest version (10.0.0-M7 : compile 'com.oath.cyclops:cyclops:10.0.0-M7') and the main thread blocks on the forEach as expected. A separate thread (possibly the one pushing data to the Queue needs to call queue.close()). Hopefully we don't have a bug in one of our older releases!

Comment: My bad, it is working as expected, I was closing the queue too early...

Comment: What a stupid mistake... I went with my own quick'n'dirty implementation https://gist.github.com/laymain/9ce194bb2924f78582e71e350672bbef

Comment: Cool - glad you got it working (and that we don't have a bug!)